# NSCell -stringValue calls -setStringValue?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextfield

In essence, here is my code in a subclass of NSTextFieldCell:

```
- (void)setStringValue:(NSString *)aString {
    [super setStringValue:aString];
    [self doSomething];
}

- (void)doSomething {
    NSLog(@"%@", [self stringValue]);
}
```

In essence, I'm trying to get my subclass notified of a change in the string value, and when the value changes, I want the subclass of NSCell to be able to do something with that new value (Using -attributedStringValue would be even better, because I want to cache it for special drawing). The problem is, for some reason, calling -(NSString *)stringValue somehow results in a call to -(void)setStringValue which ends up becoming...

...an infinite loop. Can someone enlighten me on this - and a possible workaround?

Comment: How are you calling stringValue?  I tried your code, and I didn't get any loop, it seemed to work fine.

Comment: @rdelmar I'm using the default implementation of stringValue. Maybe I missed something obvious in my code, but I'm just writing a subclass for a NSTextfieldCell which happens to be located inside an NSTableView (with the NSTextField bound to the TableCellView)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably `stringValue` is doing some lazy initialization. If it detects that it has no `stringValue` but can derive the value from something else (perhaps `attributedStringValue`?), then it derives the value, calls `[self setStringValue:derivedValue]`, then returns the value.

This does make life tricky, though.  Try something like this?

```
@implementation MyCell ()
{
    BOOL gettingStringValue;
}
@end

- (NSString*)stringValue {
    gettingStringValue = YES;
    NSString* stringValue = [super stringValue];
    gettingStringValue = NO;
    return stringValue; 
}

- (void)setStringValue:(NSString *)aString {
    [super setStringValue:aString];
    if (!gettingStringValue)
        [self doSomething];
}
```

Comment: That's a really nice solution - I wish I had thought of that beforehand - thank you!

Comment: It's not my favorite technique -- this sort of thing tends to be pretty fragile -- but sometimes it's the only way...